# Is scopolamine same as scopolamine hydrobromide?

Tags: organic-chemistry, extraction, drugs

Is scopolamine extracted with methanol or acetone from *Datura* or *Brugmansia* scopolamine free base or scopolamine hydrobromide?

If you take a look at the [Wikipedia page for hyoscine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyoscine), the *Synonyms* part lists scopolamine hydrobromide as a synonym for hyoscine even though neither molecular structure nor chemical formula contains bromine.

Comment: Is HBr involved anywhere in the process?

Comment: Scopolamine, not scolopamine. Please note it is a terrible idea to use this drug recreationally. Do yourself a favor and satisfy your curiosity in other ways.

Comment: As indicated by you, there is a form called "fee base", and an other "hydrobromide".  In the later case, one basic functional group (e.g., amine) was protonated (e.g., $\ce{|NR2 -> N+HR2 + Br-}$.  This may alter where, how, and how quickly the active ingredient enters the body (anabolism) and may influence the kinetics how it leaves the organism again (catabolism).  Hence, both chemically, as well as from medicinal perspective, treat them as "different".  If not prescribed by a physician, though, do not use such drugs for recreation.

Comment: I dont have the drug and I have no intent to use it. Asking just out of curiosity. The drug is called The devils breath and rumor is that it can zombify you by disabling free will or something. It is extracted from datura or Brugmansia as scopolamine. But some websites say the devils breath is Hyoscine ( scopolamine) hydrobromide. Do you have such information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the extraction procedure does not involve HBr, then I would doubt it is the hydrobromide because:

1. hydrobromide salts don't dissolve well in acetone;
2. hydrobromide salts are rare in nature.

According to the work by Bracci et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10/f96zpc)], the major component of MeOH extraction of *Brugmansia* is atropine.

Śramska et al. [[2](https://doi.org/10/f9wvv8)] used ethyl acetate extraction and isolated scopolamine and atropine.

No mention of hydrobromide salts in either.

#### References

1. Bracci, A.; Daza-Losada, M.; Aguilar, M.; De Feo, V.; Miñarro, J.; Rodríguez-Arias, M. A Methanol Extract of *Brugmansia Arborea* Affects the Reinforcing and Motor Effects of Morphine and Cocaine in Mice. *Evidence-Based Complementary and Alternative Medicine* **2013**, 2013, 1–7. https://doi.org/10/f96zpc.
2. Śramska, P.; Maciejka, A.; Topolewska, A.; Stepnowski, P.; Haliński, Ł. P. Isolation of Atropine and Scopolamine from Plant Material Using Liquid-Liquid Extraction and EXtrelut® Columns. *J. Chromatogr. B Analyt. Technol. Biomed. Life Sci.* **2017**, 1043, 202–208. https://doi.org/10/f9wvv8.

Comment: Any information on whether extracted scolopamine is the devils breath? By the what I think extraction is acetone. PubChem says hyoscine is soluable in acetone and doesnt mention acetone in atropine or hyoscyamine

Comment: This article says it is https://www.newsweek.com/does-devils-breath-drug-really-exist-332465 but until I see the LCMS and NMR of the extracted fractions I don't regard it as definitive. Atropine will be soluble in acetone

Comment: I am confused. If you take a look at the Wikipedia page for hyoscine. In synonyms part it says scopolamine hydrobromide is a synonym for hyoscine even though neither moleculer structure nor Chemical Formula contains bromine?

Comment: Hyoscine is the commercial name for the medical product containing scopolamine that is used to treat motion sickness etc. It is sometimes formulated as the hydrobromide to make it more water soluble and easier to take.